# Finding the ideals and irreducible components of a zero set

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $X = \{(a_1, a_2, a_3) \in \mathbb{A}^3\; | \; a_1 = 0 \text{ or }
>  a_2 = 0 \text{ or } a_3 = 0\}$     determine $I(X)$ and the irreducible
>   components of $X$.

My attempt: The set $X$ can be decomposed as the union of three zero sets, namely:

$$X = Z(x) \cup Z(y) \cup Z(z) $$

where

$$Z(x) = \{ (a_1, a_2, a_3) \in \mathbb{A}^3\; | \; a_1 = 0 \},$$

$$Z(y) = \{ (a_1, a_2, a_3) \in \mathbb{A}^3\; | \; a_2 = 0 \},$$

$$Z(z) = \{ (a_1, a_2, a_3) \in \mathbb{A}^3\; | \; a_3 = 0 \}.$$

Now, the union of zero sets can be written as the product of the each zero set, hence we have:

$$Z(x) \cup Z(y) \cup Z(z) = Z(xyz) = Z(\langle xyz\rangle).$$
$$=\{ f\in k[x,y,z]: f^k\in \langle xyz\rangle,\, k\in \mathbb{N}\} $$

The ideal $I$ can be found by noticing that
$$I(x) = \sqrt{\langle xyz\rangle}$$
where the $\sqrt{}$ denotes the radical of the ideal.

If $f^k\in \langle xyz\rangle \implies f^k = \sum a_i (xyz)$

$\implies f^k\in \langle x\rangle \cap \langle y\rangle \cap \langle z\rangle $

$\implies f\in  \sqrt{\langle x\rangle} \cap \sqrt{\langle y\rangle} \cap \sqrt{\langle z\rangle} $

However, $\langle x\rangle$, $\langle y \rangle$ and $\langle z\rangle$ are prime, so:

$\implies f\in \langle x\rangle \cap \langle y\rangle \cap \langle z\rangle $

$\textbf{irreducible components}:$ $Z(x), Z(y), Z(z)$

$\textbf{I(x)}: ? $

Comment: It seems like you have already shown that $I(X)=(xyz)$.

Comment: @Levent Thanks! I wasn't sure if my approach was correct!

Comment: I believe that it is correct. Another approach would be using the fact that $\sqrt{(f)}=(\sqrt f)$ for $f\in k[x,y,z]$. Since $xyz$ is square free you have $\sqrt{(xyz)}=(xyz)$.